# Not able to Listen New Value From Bloc Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using flutter_bloc library to manage the state of the app, as I press a button in a different class state changes in bloc class but not able to listen in BlocProvider in build method.

```
BlocBuilder<AppBarBloc, bool>(
          builder: (context, isEnabled) {
            print('state detected');
            return Container();
          },)

//in main.dart were providing the Blocs


MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<PagesBloc>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => PagesBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<AppBarBloc>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AppBarBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check this link about [bloc listener](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesfluttershowsnackbar).

But just as an example of what you can do:

```
BlocBuilder<CustomerRegisterBloc, CustomerRegisterState>
      buildCustomerRegisterOnState() {
    return BlocBuilder<CustomerRegisterBloc, CustomerRegisterState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is InitialCustomerRegisterState) {
          return PersonalDataForm();
        }
        if (state is PasswordCustomerRegisterState) {}
        if (state is PaymentFormCustomerRegisterState) {}
        if (state is TermsCustomerRegisterState) {}
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```